# Rebol and unset (optional) parameter

Tags: rebol

I want to create a do-libs generic function to automatically load a bunch of libs listed in rebol header files. I want to make the parameter optional but in that later case it doesn't work why ?

```
Rebol[
  libs: [     
    lib1/lib11.r
    lib1/lib12.r
    lib2/lib21.r
  ]
]
do-libs 'libs ; works
do-libs ; doesn't work
```

with:

```
do-libs: func[libs [word! unset!]][

  if/else value? 'libs [
    foreach lib system/script/header/:libs [
      if/else file? lib [
        do lib
      ][    
        do file: to-rebol-file mold lib
      ]      
    ]
  ][
    ;case with no parameter
    do-libs 'libs
  ]
]
```

Comment: I've switched to using R3 completely now. It's at the point where it's usable for everything I need, and its module system is really great.

Comment: Hi thanks will try it then : have never done so until now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this, but my *understanding* is that in order to create a function that allows argument omission, it has to be a literal argument, e.g.,

```
do-libs: func [ 'libs [word! unset!] ] [
    ; blah blah
]
```

Note that the libs argument is a `lit-word!`. This also means you would have to call this function as follows:

```
do-libs libs
```

OR

```
do-libs
```

However, be careful with this. REBOL does not respect new lines. If you say:

```
do-libs
3
```

It will regard 3 as an argument to `do-libs` and your function call will fail. If you say

```
do-libs
print "ok"
```

It will regard `print` as the `'libs` argument of `do-libs`. In fact, REBOL interprets the above as

```
(do-libs print) "ok"
```

The bottom line is that argument omission is intended for REBOL's interactive mode. *You shouldn't use it to do what you're trying to do*. Instead, your function should probably look like this:

```
do-libs: func [ /name 'word [word!] ] [
    if none? name [ word: 'libs ]
    ; and so on
]
```

Now you can say

```
do-libs
```

OR

```
do-libs/name foo
```

This is more natural, idiomatic REBOL. In general, refinements should be used to pass optional arguments. When the number of arguments is potentially unknown or unlimited, a `block!` should be used.

Because of how the REBOL interpreter works, it's very unlikely that REBOL will ever support the "param array" style arguments that many other languages (C, C++, Ruby, etc.) have. The interpreter would have no way of knowing where the argument list ends, unless the entire expression was placed in parentheses like so:

```
(foo 1 2 3 "a" "b" "c")
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. Well I know I should use refinements, it's just I want to understand why :)

Because this example http://reboltutorial.com/blog/optional-parameter/ did work and I didn't use a literal argument.

Comment: The reason I pass 'libs instead of lib is I don't want to be obliged to quote the lib like "lib1/lib11.r"

Comment: In R3 you can't do the argument omission unless it's quoted, but in R2 you can.  (I found this question because I was puzzling over how the viewtop function was running in R2 even when no url parameter was given.)  I don't understand the point of allowing that, using refinements is more consistent.